How to fetch logs of a failed task in informatica
i used this
https://na1.dm-us.informaticacloud.com/active-bpel/services/tf/status?runStatus=Failed 

to get all the failed jobs.
this returned a list of json objects.
The JSON object will have the subtasks too.
How do I get the logs for the task and subtask that got returned from the above API call.
Can someone guide me through it?

What have you tried so far? What is the issue you're facing?
